# Como validar la cantidad de columnas a importar PhpExcel?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpexcel

Buen día,

Alguien me puede hacer el favor de explicar o decirme como hago para que no me deje importar archivos que se pasen o tengan menos columnas de las establecidas?

Digamos si mi tabla donde voy a importar tiene 8 columnas osea de la A-H, valide si el archivo que estoy importando tiene 8 columnas si se pasa o tiene menos no importe el archivo.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo del todo tu pregunta, voy a suponer que te refieres a subir un archivo de Excel a PHP y tratarlo con la libreria PHPExcel. 
Si ese fuera el caso puedes obtener el numero de Columnas con:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestColumn();
```

O bien el numero de filas con

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
```

Incluso puedes obtener las dimensiones de la hoja con:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->calculateWorksheetDimension();
```

Este ultimo te va a devolver un rango de celdas.

Comment: Es que cuando importo un archivo  que tiene mas filas o menos que del insert aun así me lo importa.

Comment: Necesitas explicar un poco mas tu problema, poner un poco de código sería lo ideal.